# Newly committed Git branch is not showing

Tags: git, branch, git-commit, git-checkout

I'm having an issue with Git, I've switched to a new branch and committed my changes but the new branch is not showing up in the list of branches.

```
git checkout -b new-branch
git branch
 develop
 *new-branch
git commit -am 'new message'
git push -u origin new-branch
git branch -a
[here the new branch does not show]
git checkout origin/new-branch
error: pathspec 'origin/new-branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Is there a step I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer, I needed to update my remotes list

```
git remote update
```

But this also could have been that I had not added any files to the latest commit. You can check which files are to be committed using

```
git status
```

Then if you want to add everything that is not ignored by `.gitignore` then you can simply run this from your code root.

```
git add .
```

Comment: This cannot be the issue. When you pushed your branch to your remote, your local repo should already have been tracking it, there shouldn't have been a need to update from the remote, because you already know what you just pushed! **What version of Git are you using?**

Comment: Im using version 1.7.1. I know what you mean, it should have been tracking it because I literally just pushed it. Im pushing to a remote repository, I wonder if git caches that initial repository and waits for you to refresh the list?